# Future returning null first time

Tags: flutter, future, provider

Here's a class using Google Place:

```
class PlaceProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  NearBySearchResponse _places;
  NearBySearchResponse get getPlaces => _places;
  GooglePlace googlePlace;

  PlaceProvider() {
    loadAPI();
  }

  void loadAPI() async {

    await DotEnv.load(fileName: '.env');
    googlePlace = GooglePlace(DotEnv.env['API_KEY']);
  }

  Future<void> loadPlaces() async {
    print('We are here');

    _places = await googlePlace.search.getNearBySearch(
        Location(lat: 40.79, lng: -73.96), 1500,
        type: "restaurant", keyword: "hamburger");.
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Now, when I call loadPlaces(), it always makes _places null **the first time**. The second time I call it, it works just fine. What am I missing?

Here's the class using the above class:

```
class SearchPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const SearchPage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  void testPlaces(BuildContext context) {
    Provider.of<PlaceProvider>(context, listen: false).loadPlaces();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    NearBySearchResponse places = Provider.of<PlaceProvider>(context).getPlaces;
    return Column(
      children: [
        Text('Search Page'),
        ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            testPlaces(context);
          },
          child: Text('Test'),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: places == null
              ? Container(child: CupertinoActivityIndicator(radius: 50.0))
              : ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: places.results.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return Container(
                      color: Colors.grey[(index * 200) % 400],
                      child: Center(
                          child: Text(
                            places.results[index].name,
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),
                          ),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

I have added the whole app here. AS I mentioned, when the test button is pressed the first time, the value of _places remains null. The second time, the value is fine and the ListView is populated properly.

Comment: Where & how are you calling `loadPlaces()` in your code?

Comment: From a function: void getPlaces(BuildContext context) {
    Provider.of<PlaceProvider>(context, listen: false).loadPlaces();
  }        A button click fires this.

Comment: Please post that as well

Comment: Just posted the complete code

Answer (score 0):

You must use one variable for all of the two processes:
In the event button, call the variable :
code:

```
 class SearchPage extends StatelessWidget {
const SearchPage({Key key}) : super(key: key);
   

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    NearBySearchResponse places = Provider.of<PlaceProvider>(context,listen: false).getPlaces;
    return Column(
  children: [
    Text('Search Page'),
    ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: () {
           places.loadPlaces();
        
      },
      child: Text('Test'),
    ),
    Expanded(
      child: places == null
          ? Container(child: CupertinoActivityIndicator(radius: 50.0))
          : ListView.builder(
              itemCount: places.results.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Container(
                  color: Colors.grey[(index * 200) % 400],
                  child: Center(
                      child: Text(
                        places.results[index].name,
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),
                      ),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
    ),
  ],
);
  }
}
```

I hope I helped you

Comment: But "loadPlaces()" is not a member of "places". I can't call it like that.